# How to remove a cell of certain value from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've a csv file which has got a single cell at the last row. Which I need to find a delete. e.g.

> Total1254612

The value of total won't be same all the time that is causing problem.

Comment: `if len(row) == 1:
    continue` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact you know there will be only one value and that the first 5 letters will be `'Total'`. I would just rewrite all the lines that don't meet these conditions to a new file:

```
f_original = open(fname, 'r')
f_new = open(fname+'_new.csv', 'w')

#iterate through the lines
for line in f_original:
    if line.startswith('Total'):
        f_new.write(line)

f_original.close()
f_new.close()
```

Comment: Why not just use `.startswith('Total')`?

Comment: Much better, I added that in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This is iterating through the main file & write to a new file without
>   the cell 'Total'

```
f_original = open(fname, 'r')
f_new = open(fname+'_new.csv', 'w')

#iterate through the lines
for line in f_original:
    if not line.startswith('Total'):
        f_new.write(line)

f_original.close()
f_new.close()
```

> Thanks Lucas & Wilbur

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A' : [1,2,3,4],
        'B' : ['a','b','c','d'],
        })
In [3]: df.head()

           A  B
        0  1  a
        1  2  b
        2  3  c
        3  4  d
In [4]: df.drop(df.index[len(df)-1])

           A  B
        0  1  a
        1  2  b
        2  3  c
```